# My HTML files won't pair with my script.js file

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch, github-pages

- 

edit: Here is my GitHub repository for this project:

https://coreychristianclark.github.io/odin-recipes-desktop/

### Server: GitHub Pages

I've finally reached the point to where I'm about to snap my laptop in half, so I figured it'd be a good time to reach out.

When trying to load my website on to GitHub, I've noticed many things didn't show up (no CSS, no pictures, no JS). I asked GPT, and it said it was because I was using absolute paths instead of relative.

Going through, I changed everything from absolute, to relative. I noticed I forgot to do the same with my script.js, and this is where the issues started.

I am able to get my index.html working, but none of the other HTML files will work. Or, I can make all of the other HTML files work, but then index.html does not work.

I, quite simply, cannot make the pathways any more direct and clear, and I don't know why it won't load the JS on all of my pages.

This all started when I turned this fetch URL into a relative URL:

```js
const URL = "files/html-files/navBar.html";

async function loadNavbarContent() {
  try {
    response = await fetch(URL);
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
    }

    const html = await response.text();
    const navbarPlaceholder = document.querySelector("#navbar-placeholder");
    navbarPlaceholder.innerHTML = html;

    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching navbar content:", error);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  loadNavbarContent();
});

window.addEventListener("beforeunload", () => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```

My project folder is as listed:

```
odin-recipes/
  files/
    html-files/
      ...
    css-files/
      ...
    images/
      ...
    script.js
  index.html
  readme
```

I've tried absolutely everything I can think of. I'll use 'elkBurgers.html' as an example (this assumes index.html is working perfectly -- which means the other HTML files are not).

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
<script src="../script.js" defer></script>
<script src="files/script.js" defer></script>
<script src="../files/script.js" defer></script>
<script src="odin-recipes/files/script.js" defer></script>
```

Thank you for reading and providing any help.

Comment: For `index.html`: `files/script.js`. for other html files: `script.js`

Comment: Why is your `index.html` not in your `html-files` dir, though? If you have a dedicated html directory, don't make exceptions. As for what URL to use: the URL is based on how your _server_ exposes content, not the dir structure on disk, so how did you configure your server to expose your static asset directory? (and of course: which server are you using)

Comment: Can you share your github repo with us?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans op is using GitHub pages

Comment: Konrad: I tried that, but to no avail.

Mike Kamermans: I was under the impression index.html was to be at the root of the folder so the source knew which file to first pull. If that is flawed logic, I'll move it with the rest of the html files. As for the server question, I'm unsure how to answer. GPT had mentioned this as well, and I didn't know how to approach it.

CStudnet: Here is the repository: https://github.com/coreychristianclark/odin-recipes-desktop

Edit: As Konrad pointed out, I suppose the server is GitHub Pages.

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: You forgot to tag your post with `github-pages`, that covers the server and how things are supposed to work. Since your `index.html` is in the root, and your js file is `files/script.js`, `<script src="files/script.js" defer></script>` should have worked. Use that, then wait for gh-pages to rebuild (because that's _not_ immediate, look at your project's "actions" tab to see whether that's finished running) and then reload the gh-pages website with dev tools open, and set to not cache HTTP responses when dev tools is open so you know you're getting the new code instead of old, cached code.

Comment: @Mike I tried this, but to no avail. When inspecting, I get the following errors:

files/html-files/navBar.html:1     Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
script.js:16 Error fetching navbar content: Error: Network response was not ok
    at loadNavbarContent (script.js:7:13)

Is there a way to use GitHub Pages as a live server instead of VS Code? The two seem to conflict quite a bit, and I'd like to avoid having 500 commits trying to fix a small issue, but 500 different ways.

Comment: Okay, but you'll notice that's a _completely different error_, and isn't about `script.js` being loaded by your `index.html`, it's an error that's clearly telling you that your `script.js` _did_ load and it's erroring out trying to fetch a file called `files/html-files/navBar.html` relative to its own location, which is _already_ inside of `files`. So now that you solved your `script.js` load, fix the code _inside_ `script.js` to use correct URLs, too =)

Comment: "I'd like to avoid having 500 commits trying to fix a small issue" - why not resolve these errors in a different branch and merge this one once all issues are resolved?

Comment: The fetch URL in `script.js` should be `html-files/navBar.html` instead of `files/html-files/navBar.html`, because the JS file is already in the `files/` folder.

Comment: You can use interactive rebase to squash commits

Comment: Apologies for the late response. I didn't even get to touch my coding this week.

*Mike and *MfyDev That's a super good catch and I agree. That pathway seems to be the most accurate. However, when making the change, it did not fix the issue.

*Nico and *Konrad Thank you for these recommendations. I'll be looking into them today.

Comment: Edit: Oddly enough, fixing the pathway to "html-files/navBar.html" made the bar go away even with the VSCode server (which seems more forgiving than GHP).